# Typescript declare third party module locally

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm building a typescript project and using a non-typescript lib call 'draggabilly';

So I'm trying to declare it by myself.

Here is the file structure:

```
├── @types
│   └── draggabilly
│       └──index.d.ts
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── application.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

src/application.ts

```
import * as Draggabilly from 'draggabilly';

new Draggabilly('#dragItem', {
  // options...
});

......
```

it's showing that

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'draggabilly'.
>   '/node_modules/draggabilly/draggabilly.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.

So I try to create the local declaration file: @types/draggabilly/index.d.ts:

```
export as namespace draggabilly;

export = Draggabilly;

declare class Draggabilly {
  constructor(selector: string, options: any);
}
```

then include the types path in tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ......
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./@types"
        ]
    }
}
```

But the error still there. So I want to know what's wrong here and what's the correct way to build the third party module declare file locally

I created a demonstration repository for this question on github:
https://github.com/ZheFeng/test-ts-types

The issue is not only about how we define inside the .d.ts file, but also the typescript could not find a declaration file at all.

Comment: Checkout this draggabilly typings https://github.com/giespaepen/draggabilly/blob/f40f08319eb2f8c8305a6207cf9afb731232dbfe/typings/draggabilly.d.ts

Comment: Thanks Aivan, I did. But typescript seems didn't recognize my declaration file. That's why I put my file structure and config above.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the line `export = Draggabilly;` -- you have to use the TypeScript-specific syntax `import let = require("module")` to import it:

From the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

> When importing a module using export =, TypeScript-specific `import let
>   = require("module")` must be used to import the module.

So your import should be:

`import Draggabilly = require("draggabilly");`

---

If you want to use ES6-style import, you can modify your `index.d.ts` like below:

```
export as namespace draggabilly;

export class Draggabilly {
  constructor(selector: string, options: any);
}
```

... and import it like this:

```
import * as draggabilly from 'draggabilly';

new draggabilly.Draggabilly('#dragItem', {
  // options...
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But the problem is even I change to export class Draggabilly, the error still there said "Could not find a declaration file for module 'draggabilly'. '/node_modules/draggabilly/draggabilly.js' implicitly has an 'any' type".   It's seems the typescript ignore my local  declaration file

Comment: Can you just update your post with the exact code that you have. I can't seem to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help Saravana. I created a demonstration repository for this question on github: https://github.com/ZheFeng/test-ts-types

Answer (score 3):

When providing declaration file for the 3rd party module that is non-TypeScript based, the **declare module** must be in the global scope, and no **import** or **export** outside the **declare module**.

@types/draggabilly/index.d.ts

```js
declare module "draggabilly" {
    // import other libraries, optional
    // ...

    class Draggabilly {
        constructor(selector: string, options: any);
    }

    export = Draggabilly;
}
```

src/application.ts

```js
import Draggabilly = require("draggabilly");

new Draggabilly("#dragItem", {
    // options...
});
```